# sort multiple int variables by highest to lowest

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a javascript page where users answer a quiz style game with an answer.
These answers have different values depending on what they picked.

At the end of the game I would like to add these values up and sort by the highest to lowest.

Here is an example

```
type="radio" class="alcohol" name="alcohol1" value="0"

type="radio" class="alcohol" name="alcohol1" value="1"
```

I have multiple classes so alcohol is one and depression is another
When the user submits their answer I add the values of the different areas up and want to sort by highest to lowest.

Here is JSfiddle so you can see my concept

http://jsfiddle.net/ETNDw/77/

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: So to confirm, you want to sort the questions in your HTML depending on the answer value?

Comment: I want it so that when I click the button it gives me an alert for the highest scoring category...my jsfiddle shows two categories depression and alcohol. e.g. if the score was depression 3 and alcohol 6 i want the alert show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
var answer = [
        ['depression', 0],
        ['alcohol', 0]
    ];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:radio').on('change', function () {
            var name = $(this).attr('class');
            var $depression_score = 0;
            $("." + name + ":checked").each(function () {
                $depression_score = $depression_score + parseInt($(this).val());
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
                if (answer[i][0] == name)
                    answer[i][1] = $depression_score;
            }
        });
        $('#mybutton').click(function () {
            tryClicked();
        });
    });
    function tryClicked() {
        answer.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b[1] - a[1];
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
            alert("GroupName " + answer[i][0] + " ,Mark " + answer[i][1]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: tried this and it doesn't seem to be working correctly. It shows several alerts and it doesn't seem to calculate the scores correctly.

Comment: Yes did is sort of working :)..it calculates the score for the alcohol class but for some reason the depression score doesn't add up..it stays at 0 regardless of which of the options is chosen.

Comment: Thank Aravind Sivam for your help this is exactly what I was looking for!